# Can't find tsconfig.json command in Atom's toggle panel

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

I have installed atom-script package in Atom and it worked for a while well, now I can't find in toggle panel Create tsconfig.json file command anymore. What has happened? How do I add tsconfig.json file to my project then?

Comment: If you need to add an answer you can post in the answer section and accept your answer..pls dont add the solution in the question itself

Comment: @suraj, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Atom was updated last week and now doesn't create the tsconfig file within toggle panel. You need to use 'tsc --init' now to create the tsconfig file. After it is created, you need to add two lines of code so your tsconfig file will look like this:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"module": "commonjs",
"target": "es5",
"noImplicitAny": false,
"sourceMap": false
},
"compileOnSave": true,
"buildOnSave": true
}
```

The last two lines are added so when you save the typescript file, it will automatically compile the javascript file.